# Query for Counting column with Datatype Bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count

I have got a column name check , with a datatype bit(true or False), What I want to do is count how many false and true are there in the column .

```
SELECT 
COUNT(FeatureState) AS tot_true, 
COUNT(*)-COUNT(FeatureState) AS tot_false
FROM productDetail
 WHERE FeatureState= 1
```

This works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, should work:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(field) AS tot_true, 
    COUNT(*)-COUNT(field) AS tot_false
FROM table
WHERE field=1
```

Comment: cheers i just modified ur sql in d above question nd it works

Comment: @Muhammad Awais: Glad to help you! :)

Comment: Why downvote? What's wrong in my query? Please explain so I can correct it and learn something new!!

Comment: @Marco: all answers are downvoted. Some folk downote to try and flatter their own answer. If you look at timings, you can guess with some confidence who the culprit may be. +1 anyway from me.

Comment: @gbn: really bad.. this is a forum to help and get helped, not to be the best. You are doing a great job here, thanks!!

Comment: `WHERE field=true` will not run on SQL Sever (`BIT` is not the same as `BOOLEAN`). But even if you change this to `field = 1`...

Comment: ...won't `COUNT(*)-COUNT(field) AS tot_false` count the number of `NULL` values rather than the number of FALSE (`0`) values?

Comment: @onedaywhen: thanks, I assumed that in that field OP doesn't store NULL values, that's because I used this syntax...

Comment: If your assumption is correct then `tot_false` will always return zero, which I can't believe is what the OP really wants. That's why I have downvoted your answer despite it being accepted by the OP at this time.

Comment: @onedaywhen: even because OP already changed his post including my query, posted a comment telling that it works and then accepted my answer as correct... so my assumption was right. That doesn't change the fact you're right: if there is some NULL, my sql is wrong, so thanks for pointing it out... but the second downvote seems too much.. ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen: I read now your second comment. Why _tot_false_ is always zero?

Comment: Because if there are no `NULL` values involved, `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(field)` will *always* give the same result. Did you mean to use `SUM` rather than `COUNT`, I wonder?

Comment: A table with a single row `{field = 0}` should return `tot_false = 1`, right? But using your SQL it returns `tot_false = 0`, even when the `WHERE` clause is removed e.g. `WITH table1 (field) AS (SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT)) SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(field) AS tot_false FROM table1;`

Comment: @onedaywhen: sorry, I don't sleep from too much time and I'm confused... I think you could be right... I gonna check. Thanks :)

Comment: well the query works for tot_true value nd dats wat i was looking for ... d above conversation was helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

How about;

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE fld WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ZEROS,
  COUNT(CASE fld WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ONES
FROM
  T

--alternative

SELECT 
  SUM(CASE fld WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ZEROS,
  SUM(CASE fld WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ONES
FROM
  T
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used SIGN to change bit to int

```
SELECT 
    SUM(SIGN(field)) AS tot_true, 
    SUM(1-SIGN(field)) AS tot_false
FROM table
```

Or use the fact that COUNT ignores NULLs

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(NULLIF(field, 0)) AS tot_true, 
    COUNT(NULLIF(field, 1)) AS tot_false
FROM table
```

This works if you want other values MAX(SomeOtherField) where the highest values comes from the "false" rows filtered out in other solutions

Comment: Ah ha. Some tactical downvoting of all answers except one... oddly

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN FeatureState = 1     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TrueCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN FeatureState = 0     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FalseCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN FeatureState IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NullCount,
COUNT(1)                                              AS TotalCount
FROM ProductDetail
```